# Does AMD follow a similar naming scheme to Nvidia for its graphic cards?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

In this answer to [a question about the performance of Jedi Fallen on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/385660/559), user [nolonar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/46740/nolonar) gives an outstanding breakdown of how Nvidia names their cards and how that relates to performance.

Does AMD follow a similar naming scheme of Prefix, Series, Tier, Revision, and Suffix? Assuming AMD uses a predictable naming scheme how does that relate to performance of the card?

Comment: Related: [Can someone explain the naming of the different graphic card models?](https://superuser.com/q/227255/10259)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes AMD does have a naming scheme.

The first digit is the generation, currently the newest cards are the 7<sup>th</sup> generation.

The 2nd digit indicates what level the card is. A 9 is the highest performing card where as the 8 is middle of the road performance, and a 7 is low end.

They continue to get slower as the number decreases.

The 3rd digit is mostly unused, but sometimes they use a 5 to indicate it has slightly better performance than one without the 5.  Usually it means a bit higher core speed and maybe a bit more memory.

I have never observed the 4th digit to be anything but 0.

In this generation the best cards are the 7900 and the 7900XTX (top of the line).

Comment: I feel the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_RX_5000_series) actually has a good list of them sorted from "least" powerful to "most" powerful.  Also mentioned in the end of this answer was the "XTX" suffix.  With their latest cards, AMD uses "XT" and "XTX" - you can think of this as Nvidia's "Ti" suffix, with the "XTX" being even more powerful than just "XT".  I think at present there is only one "XTX" variant card.

Comment: Does the suffix `XTX` in your example mean anything?

Comment: I am sure it means something, but in terms of performance its the faster GPU.